# Angular 6 ng serve works on Windows but not OS X

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 6 app that when I run on my windows 10 machine runs without issue.

ng serve for launching the app with localhost:4200 works and the app works as expected (on any windows browser)

I then cloned the same repo on my Mac (High Sierra).

I run ng serve and the app compiles like it does on Windows, but when I navigate to any browser (safari, chrome, firefox) I get an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMOUT error from the browser.

The answers I found online do not seem to work when I apply them to my app.

I am not sure which of my files would be useful to see for this issue, I can post any specific file upon request

This is from my package.json

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/animations": "~6.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~6.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~6.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~6.0.6",
    "@angular/http": "~6.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.117"
```

I appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Comment: iOS and OS X are not the same thing.

Comment: What have you tried from other answers? Do you get anything in the cosnole after compilation?

Comment: What does `node --version`, `ng --version` print out?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Ill be honest, I really havent found any answers. I do not get any errors in the console. The site times out with no errors in the console

Comment: @yesenin Node - 9.2.0 ng - 6.0.8